# BASE Map in SSA

Tags: mapinfo, spectrum-spatial-analyst

I am trying to create a base map in my SSA implementation but just can't find the process for this in the documentation (http://support.pb.com/help/spectrum/11.1/webhelp/en/InstallationGuide-Windows/index.html)

So how do I change an imagery dataset to a "Base Map". The "Show As" option doesn't give me any choice...I believe this has to be done in mapinfo prior to uploading it as a map using the SpectrumSpatialMapUploader.mbx

[image]

Using the instructions in the documentation I have been trying to change the map config coordinate system but It won't let me edit it. I see that it depends on the base map which I have not been able to create.

Comment: What did PB say when you used your support contract?

Comment: I haven't contacted them yet. I prefer to use this forum so that then the info can be found by others and promotes the use of stackexchange. I'll contact PB if I can't get an answer here in the next couple of days and then post that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out...

I had to create a named tile from a named map.

http://support.pb.com/help/spectrum/11.1/webhelp/en/Spatial/index.html#Spatial/source/Resources/resources/repoman/create_namedtile.html

Then this can be used as a base map

This really should be included in the documentation where it talks about a base map.